# Why the output is wrong if I add an else statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

From the below code, I get the answer true, if  dont include the else statement. 
If else, statement is included, the I'm getting a false. Why is that ?

```
function search(arr, item) {


    for (let i=0; i <  arr.length; i++){  
        if (arr[i] == item){ 
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }   
}

src = search([6, 2, 3, 4], 3);
console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 3):

Every [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) ends the function.

You are checking only the first element and if you do not find the element, you return `false`. This stops the iteration as well.

Comment: correct @Nina-scholz, return False is itself the closure and next iteration will not happen !!

Answer (score 0):

This is because it will return after first check. The function that you need to use in your specific case is:

```js
function search(arr, item) {
  return arr.includes(item)  
}

const src = search([6, 2, 3, 4], 3);
console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if the first iteration doesn't match, your else will return false, it doesn't move to the next iteration.
your can try following code:

```
function search(arr, item) {
  for (let i=0; i <  arr.length; i++){  
    if (arr[i] == item){ 
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

src = search([6, 2, 3, 4], 3);
console.log(src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could also do it like this, without else condition:

```js
function search(arr, item) {
isFound=false;
for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){  
  if (arr[i] == item){ 
    isFound=true;
   }
 }   
  return isFound;
}

src = search([6, 2, 3, 4], 3);
console.log(src);
```